# Getting errors when runnig Zend application

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am new to Zend framework and trying to learn. When trying to run my Zend application I am getting following error. Can any body help me to solve this out.

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to load ZF2. Run `php composer.phar install` or define a ZF2_PATH environment variable.' in C:\websites\test\init_autoloader.php on line 53

Answer (score 0):

You should include Zend Framework library in the PHP include path.

See here for more info - http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/ref/installation.html